# msvcrt.getch() detects space every time

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, msvcrt, getch

Im writting a simple python code that should detect the my keystrokes but for some reason in detects space after everysingle keystroke.

The code:

```
import msvcrt

print("press 'escape' to quit...")
text=""
while 1:
    char = msvcrt.getch()
    print(ord(char))
```

Sample run:

```
Input: aaaaa

Output:
97
0
97
0
97
0
97
0
97
0
```

Comment: So what is the problem? what is your code printing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not detecting space. Space is `32`, not `0`.

What's happening is that you're using a wide-character terminal, but reading it as bytes, so you're seeing the UTF-16-LE bytes. In UTF-16-LE, an `a` is two bytes, `97` and `0`. If you read those as if they were two ASCII characters instead of one UTF-16-LE character, you'll get `a` followed by `\0`.

Notice that what you get back isn't actually `'a\0a\0a\0'`, but `b'a\0a\0a\0'`. So you *could* buffer these up into a `bytes` or `bytearray` and use `decode('utf-16-le')` on it. But that defeats the purpose of reading one character at a time.

The simplest fix is to use [`getwch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getwch) instead of `getch`. This will mostly just do what you want—return a single-character `str` value like `'a'` rather than two separate single-byte `bytes` values.

There may still be some problems with astral characters (everything above `U+FFFF`) showing up as two separate surrogates instead of one single character, and "special keys" will still show up as a Unicode `U+0000` or `U+00E0` followed by a keycode (or, if you have an older Python, possibly as a broken `U+E0xx` with the keycode embedded in the character). But otherwise, it'll work the way you expected.

Comment: `getch` calls `ReadConsoleInputA`, which returns keyboard input encoded according to the console's current input codepage, which defaults to OEM and cannot be set to UTF-16LE (codepage 1200). Either there is a bug in the OP's version of the C runtime, or there's a bug in the console itself (more frequent in Windows 10 since MS is actively updating the console code), or some misbehaving library or alternate terminal (e.g. ConEmu) has hooked `ReadConsoleInputA` in the current process.

Comment: @eryksun ConEmu might be a possibility—but I honestly have no idea how to walk him through diagnosing how he's screwed up his console. And I think that's probably a question for Super User, not SO. Whatever he's done, he's getting UTF-16-LE from his console, and using `getwch` will solve his problem with Python, and he hasn't asked about other problems… But if you think you can diagnose the underlying issue, that would be even better.

Comment: I don't think the Stack Exchange Q & A format is best suited for working through bugs that could be due to a broad range of problems. I've been down that road before, and it basically turns into long chats that go on for pages, which also basically doubles as a tutorial on using a debugger and other tools.

Comment: Many characters (e.g "∫") will be ignored when pasted in the console. If a pasted character isn't in the keyboard mapping (`VkKeyScan`) or isn't `C3_ALPHA` linguistic (`GetStringType` ) or isn't in a range that's East-Asian full width, then the console pastes it as an OEM Alt+Numpad sequence (or two sequences for non-BMP), i.e. encode as OEM (typically as the default "?"), convert to a decimal string, and insert a sequence of key events. The final key-up for the Alt key has the actual Unicode character value. The CRT `getwch` function does not support this pasted key event sequence.

Comment: Note that this Alt+Numpad key-event sequence is only observed with a low-level `ReadConsoleInput` call, as used by `getwch`. For a high-level `ReadConsole` and `ReadFile` call, the console only includes the actual Unicode character (or surrogate pair for non-BMP).